# Python - Pandas - How to mark elements in 1 dataframe with elements from a second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 dataframe  - lets call it dataframe 1:

```
    datetime            event name
0   31/10/1996 08:30    US-US Personal Outlays SA
1   31/10/1996 08:30    US-Personal Income
2   01/11/1996 10:00    US-ISM Manufacturing
3   01/11/1996 10:00    US-Factory Orders
4   04/11/1996 10:00    US-Construction Spending
5   07/11/1996 15:00    US-Consumer Credit
```

I have another dataframe  - lets call it dataframe 2.

```
    Event name                   Category
0   US-US Personal Outlays SA    Labor demand
1   US-Personal Income           Labor demand
2   US-ISM Manufacturing         Industrial production
3   US-Factory Orders            Industrial production
4   US-Construction Spending     Housing activity
```

I would like to add a third column 'category' to dataframe 1 that would state the category - retrieved from the dataframe2.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function for that:

```
In [336]: d1['Category'] = d1['event name'].map(d2.set_index('Event name')['Category'])

In [337]: d1
Out[337]:
           datetime                 event name               Category
0  31/10/1996 08:30  US-US Personal Outlays SA           Labor demand
1  31/10/1996 08:30         US-Personal Income           Labor demand
2  01/11/1996 10:00       US-ISM Manufacturing  Industrial production
3  01/11/1996 10:00          US-Factory Orders  Industrial production
4  04/11/1996 10:00   US-Construction Spending       Housing activity
5  07/11/1996 15:00         US-Consumer Credit                    NaN
```

explanation:

```
In [335]: d1['event name'].map(d2.set_index('Event name')['Category'])
Out[335]:
0             Labor demand
1             Labor demand
2    Industrial production
3    Industrial production
4         Housing activity
5                      NaN
Name: event name, dtype: object
```